# Comparing variables in a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Looking at other Bash scripts, I see people comparing variables like: `$S == $T` while at other times I see the variable being *wrapped* inside strings: `"$S" == "$T"`.

Some experiments seem to suggest that both do the same. The demo below will print `equal` in both cases (tested with GNU bash, version 4.2.37):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

S="text"
T="text"

if [[ $S == $T ]]; then
  echo "equal"
fi

if [[ "$S" == "$T" ]]; then
  echo "equal"
fi
```

My question: if there's a difference between `$S == $T` and `"$S" == "$T"`, what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `[[` they are almost the same, but not quite...

> When  the  ==  and  != operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is
>    considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below under Pattern
>    Matching. [...]
>    Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be matched as a string.

If you use `[` then you have to use quotes unless you know that the variables cannot be empty or contain whitespace.

*Just to be on the safe side, you probably want to quote all your variables all the time.*

Comment: Ah, cool, it's the `[...]` and `[[...]]` that makes the difference. Now I have a starting point to look in [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) for more info. Thanks Karoly!

Comment: Actually, you should double-quote at least the right operand in `[[...]]`, otherwise it'll get treated as a pattern rather than just a string (e.g. if `T='*'`, `[[ $S == $T ]]` will always be true). I recommend just double-quoting all variables rather than trying to keep track of where it's safe vs. unsafe.